# Check signature for x509 certificate

Tags: c#, .net, x509

I have:

1. x509 certificate (Base64);
2. String data;
3. Signature of string data (Base64).

Is it possible to check the signature?

My code:

```cs
bool valid = false;
    
var signature = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Signature);
var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringData);
    
var x509 = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(certificate));
var dsa = x509.PublicKey.Key as DSACryptoServiceProvider;
if (dsa!=null)
    valid = dsa.VerifySignature(data, signature);
else {
    var rsa = x509.PublicKey.Key as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
    if (rsa!=null)
        valid = rsa.VerifyHash(data, ???, signature);
}
```

I don't know what I should use instead of ???. It is possible to get the hash algorithm from the certificate?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want to check the signature of the certificate (made by its issuer) or the signature of some data, made with the private key corresponding to that certificate?

Comment: I want to check signatue of some data (stringData).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sender of the original message may use whatever algorithm he likes to sign his message, using the private key that corresponds to the certificate. While you can get the OID of the algorithm used to sign the **certificate** from the SignatureAlgorithm property, nothing prevents the sender from using a different signing or hashing algorithm.

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.verifyhash.aspx), the only valid hashing algorithms for the RSA provider are SHA1 and MD5. Perhaps you should try `VerifyHash` with both algorithms and check which one succeeds. You can get the proper OID for each one using the [CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptoconfig.mapnametooid.aspx) method like this:

```
string sha1Oid = CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1");
string md5Oid = CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("MD5");
bool sha1Valid = rsa.VerifyHash(data, sha1Oid, signature);
bool md5Valid = rsa.VerifyHash(data, md5Oid, signature);
valid = sha1Valid || md5Valid;
```

Comment: I guess you meant `CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("MD5");` for the second line.