# Self Signed X509Certificate verification with .net

Tags: c#, .net, x509, verify

here is my situation:

I've 2 X509Certificate2 objects.

- Object a: Certificate Authority (root-CA)
- Object b: Certificate ,    signed bei a.

a is not an trusted root ca!

is there an easy way to verify, that b is realy signed by a?

Comment: the right answer is in thes thread: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264747/check-signature-for-x509-certificate

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install your own Certificate validator. In your validator method you can check certificate issuer and return true if it is a.

```
 private static bool ValidateRemoteCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors policyErrors)
        {
            if ( certificate.Issuer==<a DN goes here>
                return true;
        }

        public static void InstallCertificateValidator()
        {

           ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateRemoteCertificate);


        }
```

Comment: this, is not the problem. i have to verify the cert signature

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264747/check-signature-for-x509-certificate